# How do I find all combinations of this specific list type?

Tags: python, algorithm

Sorry for a non-descripive title, I have no idea how to name this problem. If it has a specific name, let me know please.

I have a list of items. I also have a list of slots. Slot is an attribute of an item. Every item on a list is assigned to exactly one slot. There are many items assigned to one slot.

I need to find a list of all combinations where there is **one item assigned to every slot**. So, if I have the following items:

- Slot1: Item1, Item2
- Slot2: Item3
- Slot3: Item4, Item5, Item6

I want to get all combinations below

1. Item1, Item3, Item4
2. Item1, Item3, Item5
3. Item1, Item3, Item6
4. Item2, Item3, Item4
5. Item2, Item3, Item5
6. Item2, Item3, Item6

Thinking from python perspective, my output would be a list of lists (using the above example, "Item2, Item3, Item6" is one of the lists in the list of all combinations)

Important detail - I cannot just loop over every slot with nested loops, because in my program I have **17 slots**.

I have no idea how to even approach this and I have a feeling that there is a concept or a specific algorithm/data type that is required to figure this out and I just haven't learned about it yet. I'm thinking maybe this would call for some kind of recursive approach?

I would appreciate an answer that just points me in the right direction, as I want to learn, but am stuck on this for a long time now. An answer with just code would be great as well.

I'm implementing this in python, but pseudocode works too.

Comment: `product(Slot1, Slot2, Slot3)`? Check [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which in python is implemented as [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)